# What Site is a Good Example of JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I have already checked stackoverflow. Their Jquery/Javascript code is cryptic. The variables are all one letter in length. So can you guys give a good website that uses JQuery well and follows good/best practices?

I have already read many books on the subject. I would like to jquery implemented on a large scale.

Comment: To be clear: the JS code is just **minified** to save network bandwidth. This is the normal practice. Google for "js minifier" and so on for more background info.

Comment: the best way to learn jQuery is probably NOT by looking at a random web sites and trying to figure out what's going on. most sites do not use most of jQ's features . better to get some tutorials and books and learn the foundation - how it's built and works .. in fact . i daresay .. one great way to learn jQ is to carefully and purposefully work thru its implementation , jQ's source code !

Comment: "uses jQuery well/follows best practices" and "minified js" are not mutually exclusive. Plenty of great sites will minify/compress their js. In fact, minifying js *is* a best-practice. So really you want "uses JQuery well and follows good/best practices and does not minify their js".

Comment: Re-reading your question, you are implying that SO, by virtue of minifying their js and making their code "cryptic", is *not* a site that uses jQuery well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the jQuery's homepage [jQuery.com](http://jquery.com) you can find several [tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials).

Further on there are books written about jQuery. The one I can recommend is the [jQuery in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988355). It's a pleasant read.

Here's a showcase of sites which use jQuery:
http://usejquery.com

Here are more topics about the subject:
[Where can I find a tutorial to get started learning jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168802)
[Where can I learn jQuery? Is it worth it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27242)

Comment: Yea..I have already read many books on jquery. I would like to see jquery in action by some sites that use it well

Comment: I updated my answer with a link to a showcase site.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend the site [LearningJQuery](http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/08/what-is-this).

They've got advanced, intermediate and beginner examples.

I'd suggest that any site who is using the minified jQuery library is doing themselves and their visitors a favour!

Comment: And not only minified, but also supplied with proper response headers such as ETag, Last-Modified and Expires :)

Answer (score 2):

How about [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) itself?

Comment: Jquery.com has alot of regular javascript in it. They don't use much jquery

Comment: Have you actually looked at the source code? view-source:http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials

Comment: Down-vote because it is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: SeaHag: Did you actually read the question? Which answer did you upvote, and why is that more relevant than my answer?

Comment: +1 to counter Sea Hag being, well, as the name implies.  This is definitely relevant.

Comment: If the OP has already read multiple books on jQuery and still doesn't understand how to use it, looking into the library code itself will be much too confusing. I up-voted pcambell and balusc for their references to learning sites. I am not saying looking into the jQuery source code isn't beneficial in learning javascript in general, because it definitely is. I just don't feel it is going to help the OP.

Comment: +1 from me too.  You shouldn't be downvoted for answering the question that was asked.