# Javascript: cannot find the bug on a slideshow

Tags: javascript, debugging, slideshow, slide

I have two sliders on a website. the first slide works ok, but the second slide is bugged on the "slide right" button. I have checked the code even with a visual diff of the code and there is no difference (apart from the component names) between the two slides.

I have made a JSfiddle of the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/sfcRJ/
EDIT: jquery was missing, this works: http://jsfiddle.net/sfcRJ/1/

This is the JS of the first slide:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

$('#slider').css({
    width: slideWidth,
    height: slideHeight
});

$('#slider ul').css({
    width: sliderUlWidth,
    marginLeft: -slideWidth
});

$('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

function moveLeft() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
        left: +slideWidth
    }, 200, function () {
        $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
        $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
};

function moveRight() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
        left: -slideWidth
    }, 200, function () {
        $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
        $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
};

$('a.control_prev').click(function () {
    moveLeft();
});

$('a.control_next').click(function () {
    moveRight();
});

});
```

This is the JS of the second slide:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

var slideCount = $('#profes ul li').length;
var slideWidth = $('#profes ul li').width();
var slideHeight = $('#profes ul li').height();
var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

$('#profes').css({
    width: slideWidth,
    height: slideHeight
});

$('#profes ul').css({
    width: sliderUlWidth,
    marginLeft: -slideWidth
});

$('#profes ul li:last-child').prependTo('#profes ul');

function moveLeft() {
    $('#profes ul').animate({
        left: +slideWidth
    }, 200, function () {
        $('#profes ul li:last-child').prependTo('#profes ul');
        $('#profes ul').css('left', '');
    });
};

function moveRight() {
    $('#profes ul').animate({
        left: -slideWidth
    }, 200, function () {
        $('#profes ul li:first-child').appendTo('#profes ul');
        $('#profes ul').css('left', '');
    });
};

$('a.ctrl_prev').click(function () {
    moveLeft();
});

$('a.ctrl_next').click(function () {
    moveRight();
});

});
```

Unfortunately The fiddle does not work at all and I have no clue why. I'm quite new to js and I have a very hard time debugging it.

Can someone have a look at the code and help me find what's wrong?

EDIT: It seems that the slideshow works with three slides but not with two. Looking at the code, I cannot find the reason of this behaviour, expecuially since the slideshow on the right works with the previous button but not with the right button. Why this is happening?

Comment: Your fiddle missed the jquery library http://jsfiddle.net/sfcRJ/1/

Comment: You have no jQuery included [see this](http://jsfiddle.net/sfcRJ/2/)

Comment: you should include jquery library from the dropdown available on the left in your JSfiddle. It is working fine.

Comment: Do you want it to work with two images? Or is my answer enough for you?

Comment: I'm so damn blind. I was so struggling with the slide that I totally forgot jQuery. But the main question is still there. As @Niklas pointed out, why the slideshow does not work with just two slides?

Comment: Yes @Niklas, the right one needs to have only two slides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no difference between the two sliders except that you have three `li` objects with images on the left one, but only two on the right one.

It's a bit of a hack getting it to work with only two images since you have a fixed width on your slider. You widen the slider by another image, clone the first child, append it and then remove it when the animation is done.

```
function moveRight1() {
    if (slideCount1==2) {
        $('#profes ul').css('width', sliderUlWidth1+slideWidth1);
        $('#profes ul li:first-child').clone().appendTo('#profes ul');
    }
    $('#profes ul').animate({
        left: -slideWidth1
    }, 200, function () {
        if (slideCount1==2) $('#profes ul li:last-child').remove();
        $('#profes ul li:first-child').appendTo('#profes ul');
        $('#profes ul').css('left', '');
    });
};
```

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sfcRJ/69/)

Comment: This baffles me. Why would not work with just two slides? the right one needs to have only two. How do I fix it to work with two?

Comment: Niklas you saved my day, thanks a lot. Could you suggest me a resource  to learn to do what you did? I have a huge gap there that I need to fill it.

Comment: The way I learned was using jQuery in web projects over the last two years. But I'd say that the fastest way of learning is helping others, like here on stackoverflow. Try answering a question about jQuery once every other day and you'll learn faster than you think. Also, check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27242/where-can-i-learn-jquery-is-it-worth-it

Answer (score 1):

you should include jQuery library. Try this from the dropdown available on the left in your JSfiddle. It is working fine.

you can debug and find errors using developer console available in browsers.

chrome browser has debugger available in it, please refere [Chrome Javascript debugger](http://www.pascarello.com/lessons/browsers/ChromeDebugHelp.html)

you can refer to various debugging techniques at 
[Advanced JavaScript Debugging Techniques](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/04/03/advanced-javascript-debugging-techniques/)

Comment: These are great comments, but they're not an answer.